# How to remove all the duplicates in a list using scheme (only abstract list functions allowed)

Tags: scheme

I know how to write this in an recursive way.

```
(define (removed2 lst)
  (cond
       [(empty? lst) empty]
       [(not (member? (first lst) (rest lst)))
        (cons (first lst) (removed2 (rest lst)))]
       [else (removed2 (rest lst))]))
```

so (removed2 (list 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3)) gives (list 1 2 3)

However, how do you rewrite it only using abstract functions (filter, foldr, map, and build-list)?

I tried to use filter but it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to use `foldr` for this, the trick is knowing what to write in the `lambda`:

```
(define (removed lst)
  (foldr (lambda (e a)
           (if (not (member? e a))
               (cons e a)
               a))
         '()
         lst))
```

Also check if your interpreter has a built-in function, for instance in Racket you can use `remove-duplicates`.

Comment: yes, but Racket docs http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#(def._((lib._racket/private/list..rkt)._foldr))  says `foldl` runs in constant space, and `foldr` in O(n) space. :)

Answer (score 2):

**FILTER**

Just for kicks, a version with `filter`:

```
(define (make-unique-filter)
  (let ((seen '()))
    (lambda (e)
      (if (member e seen)
          #f
          (begin
            (set! seen (cons e seen))
            #t)))))

(define (removed2 lst)
  (filter (make-unique-filter) lst))
```

then

```
(removed2 (list 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3))
=> '(1 2 3)
(removed2 (list 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3))
=> '(1 2 3)
```

**FOLD**

But of course, *fold* is the way to go. However, it is generally preferable to user a *left fold* (at least in Racket, see [here](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/private/list..rkt%29._foldr%29%29)), but the result has to be reversed:

```
(define (removed2 lst)
  (reverse 
   (foldl 
    (lambda (e a)
      (if (not (member e a))
          (cons e a)
          a))
    '()
    lst)))
```

or in pure Scheme:

```
(define (removed2 lst)
  (reverse 
   (fold-left 
    (lambda (a e)
      (if (not (member e a))
          (cons e a)
          a))
    '()
    lst)))
```