# How to convert the explicit recursive functions into Higher-Order/Abstract Functions in Scheme

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket, fold, higher-order-functions

I am wondering how to convert the explicit recursive functions below into a higher-ordered/abstract functions using foldr, map, filter, etc in Scheme/Racket.

```
(define (insertNoDups f element lst)
  (cond[(empty? lst) (cons element lst)]
       [(f element (first lst)) lst]
       [else (cons (first lst) 
                   (insertNoDups f element (rest lst)))]))

(define (remove-dups f lst)
  (cond[(empty? lst) empty]
       [else (insertNoDups  f 
                            (first lst) 
                            (remove-dups f (rest lst)))]))
```

Answer (score 0):

insertNoDups (rename it to insert-no-dups) : use `member-procedure` *predicate* (more info -> http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/Searching-Lists.html) and cons `element` to the front if not found.

remove-dups: look at Óscar López's answer here -> [How to remove all the duplicates in a list using scheme (only abstract list functions allowed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21298989/how-to-remove-all-the-duplicates-in-a-list-using-scheme-only-abstract-list-func) and use `member-procedure` *predicate* instead of `member?`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But what I want is to combine the two functions above into one functions that using abstract function. Also "f" in the functions refers to a function that consumes two variables like (lambda (x y)...). Can you help me to figure out this? thx.

Comment: isn't that hard to figure out, might be worthwhile to investigate the concepts you want to apply. Because at the moment it seems that you don't have an idea what they do.

Comment: I really have no idea about this... I've trying a whole day to translate these functions into a abstract function, but nothing come up... Any help please..